# Mediawiki (1.26) - How to access a 404 HTTP-status from within Page

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, mediawiki

when calling a non-existent wiki page mediawiki delievers a 404 in the header.

Is there a way to catch this from the own page (for logging reasons)?

There is a

```
public function getStatusCode()
```

in WebResponse.php and in HttpError.php

and in OutputPage.php e.g. there is a

```
public function setStatusCode( $statusCode )
```

From within the MonoBookTemplate.php i have an instance of MonoBookTemplate.

But how do i catch from this place the 404 status?

I read about `$context->getOutput()` but have no clue how to access the status variable.

---

Part-Solution:

As a workaround i added `$wgMyStatusCode` to the `LocalSettings.php`
and in `WebResponse.php`:

```
public function statusHeader( $code ) {
    HttpStatus::header( $code );

    //added
    global $wgMyStatusCode;
    $wgMyStatusCode = $code;
}
```

Anyway - if someone could me introduce to the secrets of object-orientation in mediawiki - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
!RequestContext::getTitle()->exists()
```

is probably close enough.